# IllegalStateException : PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged, fragmentstatepageradapter

When should `notifyDataSetChaned` be called?

I am using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

I have one item in my dataset. I add a new item to my dataset. But I do not make any changes to `viewPager`. No touch event or any user generated event is passed. I  call `notifyDataSetChaned` after some time. But before `notifyDataSetChanged` is called, I get the IllegalStateException.

If I call `notifyDataSetChaned` immediately after adding the item. I do not get this exception.

This seems to be timing issue. Why is it so?